# Why instantiation of a typealias of a tuple does does not convert to the type of a variable that had been declared as the same typealias?

Tags: swift, xcode, type-conversion, type-alias

What is causing this error. I would like to know that more than the solution to get around the error. I am using Swift in Xcode 13.4 on macOS Monterey 12.4.

When I use the following `typealias` to instantiate the type in a `CKModifyRecordsOperation.perRecordSaveBlock`, switch result success(CKRecord) case, I get an error at code time.

The `CKRecord` object has the following definition in the CloudKit schema:

```
RECORD TYPE Contact (
    "___createTime"        TIMESTAMP QUERYABLE SORTABLE,
    "___createdBy"         REFERENCE QUERYABLE,
    "___etag"              STRING QUERYABLE SEARCHABLE SORTABLE,
    "___modTime"           TIMESTAMP QUERYABLE SORTABLE,
    "___modifiedBy"        REFERENCE QUERYABLE,
    "___recordID"          REFERENCE QUERYABLE,
    debugTag               STRING QUERYABLE SEARCHABLE SORTABLE,
    ownerContactIdentifier STRING QUERYABLE SEARCHABLE SORTABLE,
    referenceToGroupRecord REFERENCE QUERYABLE,
    vCardContactData       BYTES,
    GRANT WRITE TO "_creator",
    GRANT CREATE TO "_icloud",
    GRANT READ TO "_world"
);
```

I see that the error message I get says that the tuple type I am assigning to my variable is not convertible to the tuple type that I had declared the variable with the same tuple type. The only difference I see is that the first parameter has a parentheses around it in the tuple type of the value I am assigning to the variable, whereas the tuple type of the variable does not have a parentheses in the first parameter.

```
typealias TupleContactRecord =
    (contactRecord: CKRecord,
     ownerContactIdentifier: String?,
     localContactIdentifier: String?,
     contact: CNContact?,
     vCardUnarchiveError: Error?,
     contactSaveError: Error?,
     setLocalContainerIdentifierFieldOfContactRecordError: Error?,
     saveRecordError: Error?)
```

Code time error message:

> Tuple type '(contactRecord: (CKRecord), ownerContactIdentifier: String?, localContactIdentifier: String?, contact: __CKRecordObjCValue?, vCardUnarchiveError: _const Error?, contactSaveError: _const Error?, setLocalContainerIdentifierFieldOfContactRecordError: _const Error?, saveRecordError: _const Error?)' is not convertible to tuple type 'TupleContactRecord' (aka '(contactRecord: CKRecord, ownerContactIdentifier: Optional, localContactIdentifier: Optional, contact: Optional, vCardUnarchiveError: Optional, contactSaveError: Optional, setLocalContainerIdentifierFieldOfContactRecordError: Optional, saveRecordError: Optional)')

Just below is the pertinent code, stripped to the very minimum so that I only get that one error and no other errors. I marked where the error message appears. The red underline appears under the capital "T" of the typealias on the same line as the error message.

```
if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
    
    modifyRecordsOperation.perRecordSaveBlock = {
        
        recordID, saveResult in
        
        var newTuple: TupleContactRecord? = nil
        
        switch saveResult {
            
        case .failure(let error):
            
            break
            
        case .success(let savedContactRecord):
            
            newTuple = TupleContactRecord(contactRecord: savedContactRecord, // error message appears here.
                                          ownerContactIdentifier: savedContactRecord[DatabaseNameStrings.fieldOwnerContactIdentifier],
                                          localContactIdentifier: savedContactRecord[DatabaseNameStrings.fieldLocalContactIdentifier],
                                          contact: savedContactRecord[DatabaseNameStrings.fieldVCardContactData],
                                          vCardUnarchiveError: nil,
                                          contactSaveError: nil,
                                          setLocalContainerIdentifierFieldOfContactRecordError: nil,
                                          saveRecordError: nil)
            
        } // switch saveResult {...}
        
    } // modifyRecordsOperation.perRecordSaveBlock {...}

} // if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {...}
```

Comment: `CNContact` isn't one of the supported types of `CKRecord`. This won't work in the first place. What are you actually storing in the record?

Comment: I just put in my post the definition of the record type as found in the CloudKit schema. The CNContact is stored in the field vCardContactData.

Comment: Oh in that case you can get it as `Data` or `NSData`. I still don't know how a `CNContact` is represented though, so I can't tell you how to convert the data to `CNContact`. For example, if you have used `NSKeyedArchiver` to archive it, then use `NSKeyedUnarchiver`.

Comment: I noticed that when I cast the argument for the "contact" parameter to CNContact, the error disappears. I just don't know why the error message shows that the first argument of the value I'm assigning to the variable has a parentheses around it like so "(CKRecord)", while the variable type doesn't have a parentheses around it like so "CKRecord".

Comment: This tuple is a nightmare, you should use a struct for such a long-lived, complex datatype.

Comment: @Alexander Yes. I think you're right. I probably don't need to keep up with every error I get. There may not be anything I could do to fix certain errors.

Comment: @daniel I have no idea where you got that from, I said no such thing

Comment: @Alexander I wasn't repeating what you said. I was saying I don't need the tuple at all. The tuple collects any possible error that occurs at each step of the process. I don't know what the common practice is among programmers. I probably should handle each error when it occurs, rather than to save the Error object until the end of the process. Keeping up with all errors may be helpful during development, but the app has to be released for sale as quickly as practical.

Comment: @daniel ah you’re talking about runtime errors, I thought you were talking about compile time errors. Yeah, errors should be handled as soon as practical, at the appropriate level of the architecture that can do something useful with them